# Adding an event to an event structure

Tags: events, structure, labview

I'm a complete newb to labview. I don't seem to be able to add or change the events in the Event Structure. I used get a "Edit Events" dialogbox but now, nothing. What is happening, what should i do?

Greets,
Yohann

Comment: What version of the LabVIEW development system do you have? It used to be the case that you couldn't create event structures in the Base Package development system - you could run a VI which already contained them but not create new ones. This limitation was removed at least a couple of years ago.

Comment: Hi,
I'm running 2013, after reinstalling it worked perfectly.

Answer (score 1):

Right click on the event structure, you should see an option to add an event: [image].

Answer (score 0):

Thanks,

It didn't help.
I've reinstalled the software and now it works just fine.

Comment: Please mark as answered even if you answered your own question.